# Reputable source to get foot traffic in Australia based on different locations

Tags: data-request, traffic, extracting, australia

I am interested in hourly foot traffic in Australia based on various locations. Let's say I choose a certain restaurant's location in Melbourne and set a 1km radius to measure the traffic hourly.

Is there a appropriate way where I could retrieve the historical hourly traffic? Or, if I need to pay for the historical data, do you have any recommendations on websites or analytics company I could reach out for?

Answer (score 1):

There is no open data source that I am aware of that would be able to provide foot traffic at the hourly level for the method you are looking for. That being said, an option would be to look up recent traffic studies and see if they include pedestrian and bicycle counts for the study area you are looking at.

On the commercial side, you can talk with the persons at [AirSage](https://airsage.com/) and ask them for data to figure out slow moving individuals who progress through the area. They use cell phone data to develop traffic volumes in an area, you would need to find a way to separate vehicular from foot traffic.